# Animals eating animals - Noah

Tags: flood-of-noah

I have a question, its bothering me. 
Noah saved all the animals from the flood, when the flood was over Noah released the animals as well including lions tigers and other now known to be meat eaters.

If lions or tigers started eating other animals that means not many will be left. 
My question is, were all the lions and tigers where grass eating? in the Holy Bible it does says in future they will be eating grass

Comment: This question can really only be answered by speculation. Here's mine: Noah could have delayed releasing the carnivores until their prey had time to spread out and start breeding further.

Answer (score 1):

It was not until after the flood, and most likely; after the animals had begun to procreate, that there were any carnivores on the Earth.

> Genesis 9:2 and 3 NKJV  And the fear of you and the dread of you shall be on every beast of the earth, on every bird of the air, on all that move on the earth, and on all the fish of the sea. They are given into your hand. 3  Every moving thing that lives shall be food for you. I have given you all things, even as the green herbs.

Before that time all creatures including man were Herbivorous.

> Genesis 1:29  And God said, "See, I have given you every herb that yields seed which is on the face of all the earth, and every tree whose fruit yields seed; to you it shall be for food. 30  Also, to every beast of the earth, to every bird of the air, and to everything that creeps on the earth, in which there is life, I have given every green herb for food"; and it was so.

Comment: You should know better than to answer a truth question.  You've been here for a while now.  Also, I do not believe it is scientifically true that there were no carnivores before the flood - assuming that the flood literally happened.  There were animals before humans.

Comment: @TheFreemason I did not read this as a truth question only one asking for clarification. For some reason which I cannot understand People on this site no longer seem to read what people are asking, and distort almost everything into something not in the question. I only am able to hear the question, so maybe I perceive things differently than others. I only listen to the question and try to answer it in the way it is asked. This question in my mind is not asking if anything is true or not only for clarification of some apparent discrepancy in the Scriptures.

Comment: I sometimes have to wonder if my blindness is a handicap or an advantage.